# 9000+ different subdomains 301 to main domain, .htacess apache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I bought a domain that had various subdomains such as

Kim.domain.com/whatever
john.domain.com/whatever1
Lizo.domain.com/whatever2
Simon.domain.com/whatever1

And this was in the thousands, and also had links to these pages

I'd like to do a 301 redirect for all these urls into
http://domain.com

Any idea how this could be done?

This is for a apache web server and needs to be done via .htaccess

I have implemented the solution from reading the answer below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http:/ / www. domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However I have a slight problem, I would like to redirect all subdomains + subfolders to http://www. domain.com/

With the exception of http: //domain. com/subfolder/, in which case I would like to redirect to http: // www.domain. com/subfolder/ [i.e. exception for no subdomain]

I'm guessing I need to add an exception, what can I do to implement this.

**Note: example URLs above have had spaces added to them to prevent spam blocks for blocking the post.**

Comment: Do you have any subdomains you DON'T want to rewrite? Working backwards that way would be quicker.

Comment: Nope, I want to rewrite all the domains. The answer below helped me find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you intend to lose the "kim" part and retain the "whatever" part so that kim.domain.com/whatever redirects to domain.com/whatever ?  If so, then drop this into every site's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I assume you want this in .htaccess because you want to get rid of kim, john, lizo and simon but keep larry, moe and curly.  If you do this, then I suggest creating one htaccess file in one directory, and setting that directory as the DocumentRoot of all of the virtualhosts you want to "get rid of".

If you want to get rid of *everything* but "domain.com", you can improve performance by getting rid of all the virtual hosts entirely, having just one site, and in your apache configuration doing (see "[Canonical Hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost)")

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If the requested host is not "domain.com" and it's not blank (http 1.0 and broken clients that don't send a Host: header), then it redirects the user to domain.com.  This saves the server from having to figure out what virtual host a client wants then looking for and reading the htaccess file.

If you don't want the "whatever" part, RewriteRule becomes

```
RewriteRule . http://domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer your the question, it was very thorugh and covered all the bases. I found the other guys answer to work, after a few bit of playing around. He got there just a second or so before you. p.p.s ignore the previous message thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/ [L,R=301]

Basically what this says is that if the HTTP_HOST doesn't match domain.com, do a 301 redirect to http://domain.com. Be careful to escape any `.` in the in RewriteCond.

If you want to keep the folder after the hostname, so that `http://kim.domain.com/whatever` redirects to `http://domain.com/whatever`, you can replace the last line with:

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Thanks very much, worked perfectly.. I left a few comments before about this not working, I managed to figure it out. I have the site set up to force www.domain.com, so I guess they were conflicting each other. I managed to fix it but change domain.com to www.domain.com from the above examples. Thanks very much for your help Niall